# after history.back() function, next codes are running

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
    $ok_register = 0;
    if($ok_register != 1) {
?>
        <javascript type="text/javascript">
            alert("1");
            history.back();
        </javascript>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

<javascript type="text/javascript">
    alert("2");
    location.replace('./bbb.php');
</javascript>
```

if run this code, "alert("1");" this line excute, and "alert("2");location.replace('./bbb.php')" those line excute, too.

give me answer, why after "history.back();" lines excute.

Comment: I think you need to put this js in some functions if you dont want to execute automaticly when page loads nad then call function when you need to execute

Answer (score 1):

So what do you expect from this code if you using abnormal scripts tag? 
use `<script></script>` and put your javascript there

Comment: I think that when 'history.back()' function excute, at that time page return to back page and next two line don't excute.
I did <script></script> but it was same.

Comment: you can to call other two lines only on pages when it need; also you can to use 'return' for exit from script and if{}else{} construction;